# How can I find Triangle base length?

Tags: triangles

How can I find base length of the triangle in attached picture?

Can I use mid-segment theorem to find the base?

[image: triangle base]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know about [similar triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similar_triangles)?

Comment: Surely what OP is asking is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the base of the small triangle is parallel to the base of the large triangle you can set up proportions.

Which would give you $${8\over 5}={18\over x}$$ Which you could solve for x: $$8x=90\implies x={45\over 4}=11.25$$

So the base of the large triangle would be $11.25$